# сколлинг обновляемого div с помощью selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, прокрутка

Подскажите как можно решить следующую проблему:

есть контейнер (div) в котором отображается N элементов (других div), у контейнера есть scroll (поскольку суммарный размер дочерних элементов больше размера контейнера)

если прокрутить скролл до самого низа, то подгружается еще M элементов и скролл опять отъезжает, если прокрутить скролл вниз, то все повторится

и так до тех пор пока все элементы не будут подгружены

Хочу добиться того, чтобы все элементы были загружены, т.е. крутить скролл, подгружать элементы и еще раз крутить скролл

Однократно, как я понимаю, можно сделать просто:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
my_container.executeScript("scroll(0, 1000)");
```

Но как сделать многократно до тех пор, пока скролл не будет отскакивать из-за подгрузки нового контента?

Не хотелось бы делать в лоб через цикл и ожидание конца подгрузки  (несколько секунд)

Есть же какие-то правильные решения?

P.S.

в лоб сделал таким образом:

```
for i in range(100):
    driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollBy(0, 1000);", my_container)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

проблема что есть выставляемая мной задержка и фиксированное кол-во попыток промотать

Comment: Ну а как еще, если не через цикл? скроллим, ждем, проверяем "можно или еще скроллить" - повторяем до победного.